# DWG or other 2D File Versioning in OSS Buckets

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

How can we maintain multiple versions of the same DWG or other 2d file while uploading and translating the file. What are the preferred options.

I need to maintain the versioning of the files in Private OSS Bucket with Autodesk Forge and not using BIM360 in this case.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

OSS is just a simple blob storage service and as such it does not provide any versioning capability. You can introduce your own versioning schema, though, for example by appending a version suffix to the object key of every uploaded file (and then removing the suffixes when listing the objects), or by maintaining the document-version relationships (and then perhaps even folder-document relationships) in a relational database, with version records pointing to OSS objects.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions !

Comment: Hi Petr - One more question on similar lines. What if the file name itself changes in the host application. I guess OSS does not provide such functionality to update the file name/objectkey for all the associated versioned files. What could be the best way to handle such scenario. Thanks very much.